# IndexOutOfBoundsException: while getting title of menu item (overflow icon) items

Tags: android, menuitem, indexoutofboundsexception, android-menu

I am trying to set a specific username to a specific menu item, then get it using

```
  LoggedUser = (String) menu.getItem(R.id.User).getTitle().toString();
```

like :

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    menu.findItem(R.id.User).setTitle("username");
    LoggedUse0r=(String) menu.getItem(R.id.User).getTitle().toString();
    invalidateOptionsMenu();
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

I declared

```
invalidateOptionsMenu();
```

in different methods like

```
onCreate(), onStart(), onResume()
```

However, my app crashes and gives me this exception:

> 11-02 07:44:52.112 8714-8714/com.example.prof_mohamedatef.listview
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                        java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 2131492986, size is
>   4
>                                                                                            at
>   java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)
>                                                                                            at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:304)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.getItem(MenuBuilder.java:729)
>                                                                                            at
>   com.example.prof_mohamedatef.listview.Booking_hotels.onPrepareOptionsMenu(Booking_hotels.java:194)
>                                                                                            at android.app.Activity.onPreparePanel(Activity.java:2570)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onPrepareOptionsPanel(FragmentActivity.java:532)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onPreparePanel(FragmentActivity.java:521)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onPreparePanel(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:93)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase$AppCompatWindowCallbackBase.onPreparePanel(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:355)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.preparePanel(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1380)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.doInvalidatePanelMenu(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1633)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.access$100(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:93)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9$1.run(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:129)
>                                                                                            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
>                                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>                                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5283)
>                                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>                                                                                            at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
>                                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
>                                                                                            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Can any body tell me what's the relation between getting String of item's title 
and this type of exception:

```
IndexOutOfBoundsException:
```

your response will be appreciated, Thanks in advance

Comment: will you post your whole code here .........

Comment: `menu.findItem(R.id.User).getTitle().toString();`

Comment: You have to find the item with id..the correct way is one given by @RandykaYudhistira

Comment: @RandykaYudhistira thanks, this is the exact solution

Comment: @sunilsunny thanks for reply, you are right

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this.

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.your_menu, menu);

    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.your_menu_item);
    String loggedInUser = item.getTitle().toString();
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are passing `View` Id to `menu.getItem(R.id.User)`. According to the documentation

> **MenuItem getItem (int index)**
>
> Gets the menu item at the given index.

So instead use it like so:

```
menu.getItem(0...3);    // since the size of menu items is 4.
```

Answer (score 0):

I solve this issue after I use **findItem()** instead of **getItem()**.

so this will solve your issue:

```
MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item);
```